# In swift, how to set initial view for tabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have 5 tabs in tabBarController.[image: iamge]

Every time I run it, it will show the first tab view.

However I would like my middle tab (tab 3) to be the one that is first displayed when the app tun to tabBarController(if log in success).

How to do that?

---

when i add

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
```

the middle button was been highlighted, but the view hasn`t been displayed.
how to deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
func viewDidLoad (){
       self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
}
```

You select the index when your viewController is loaded. If you want select it only when the user is logged:

```
func viewDidLoad (){
       if userLogged{
           self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2
       }
}
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad` might be called more than once, so you should also have something to track whether this is the first time the view is loaded or not.

Comment: I should add these code in which viewDidLoad?

Comment: Where you need it.

Comment: the middle button was been highlighted, but the view hasn`t been displayed. how to deal with that?

Comment: var svc:SecondViewController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2] as SecondViewController
svc.delegate = self OR self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2]